# Checking in changes to TFVC from other solutions

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013, azure-devops, tfvc

I am using Visual Studio Online. I have projects which have common code that I use across a number of different solutions in different TFS projects and I also have some files which are linked from other TFS projects in some of them.  In order to be able to access them all, I've changed the Workspace config so that I have just mapped $/ to a particular folder.

The problem is that I just checked in a change in one project and noticed that it also checked in a change in a completely unrelated one that wasn't part of the solution at all!  How can I configure things to be able to access everything that I need to without cross-checking-in files from unrelated projects (and without having to manually exclude/include files in every check in)!?

EDIT: I've noticed that this doesn't seem to have happened again on my last couple of check ins when I also had items from other projects checked out.  Wondering what caused it.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at a NuGet solution for this. If you are using VSO you can use the new [MyGet integration](http://blog.myget.org/post/2014/05/12/Announcing-Visual-Studio-Online-integration.aspx) with an automated build process. If you create an automated build for the shared project output that is packaged in a NuGet package you can create a NuGet repository ion MyGet to provide it to your other solutions.

Once you have that, if you then change the shared code and check in, the build and package will kick off and deploy your new version of the package. Your other solutions will then prompt you to update automatically. You don't even need to check in the dependent assemblies as you can use [NuGet Package Restore](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/package-restore) to make sure your local and build server get the right versions.

It sounds like a lot of work but once you get up to speed it only takes a few hours of investment to configure for anything you want to share or deploy in this way.

Comment: Interesting idea, but it isn't just a matter of keeping builds up to date - I add to the shared code as I come across things I need in each project, so I do actually want the source available for a quick change and build too

Comment: Its really just bad practice to use a shared code approach. If you make a breaking change to a share project you could end up making a whole bunch of stuff not compile. And what if you have 20 things using the shared code and you need to update to a newer version for 21... when do you go back and fix the other 20? Coz they are now broken... you can't do anything, including bug fixes until you fix that. Better to do voluntary pull from a binary repository..

Answer (score 1):

In the Pending Changes section of Team Explorer, in the Included Changes section there is a drop down. If it's set to "Show All" you'll see changes pending for all your solutions. If it's set to "Show Solution Changes" you'll just see changes pending for the current solution. (My guess is that it was set to "Show All" when you checked in your changes and that's why you got changes from other solutions checked in.)